# Using OAuth authentication with ASP.NET 5 (vnext) MVC6 beta5 (without Asp.Net Identity)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, oauth-2.0, adfs

I am trying to use OAuth Authentication with ASP.NET 5 MVC6 beta5 without using ASP.NET Identity.

For now, I have put in place a simple cookie authentication that sign in the user if the login specified in the login form exists in the database, whatever password was entered (I don't store passwords for users in the database).

Here are the packages I use:

```
"dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuth": "1.0.0-beta5",     
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Net.Http.Server": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
},
```

I have set up the cookie authentication like this in Startup.cs Configure method (just before app.UseMvc):

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
});
```

Here is my Login method located in the Account Controller:

```
//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User user = securityService.FindUserByUserName(model.UserName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName) };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                Context.Authentication.SignIn(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            }
        }

    return View(model);
}
```

Here is my LogOff method located in the Account Controller:

```
//
// POST: /Account/LogOff
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult LogOff()
{
    Context.Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Now, I would like to use OAuth Authentication middleware as demonstrated here to authenticate the user against AD FS: [Authenticating ASP.NET 5 to AD FS OAuth](https://vcsjones.com/2015/05/04/authenticating-asp-net-5-to-ad-fs-oauth/)

But I have no idea as to how to specify in the Login action to use this middleware for authentication (while passing the login and password entered in the login view's form).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to show both Auth types and segregate based on source or another factor, I'd dig into MVC6 Filters, the 
Authorization on in particular.  if you want to do a hybrid (cookies if external user, oauth through ADFS if internal, you can have the login Post back a diff route: i.e. /api/Login vs /Login based on input.  So if you are trying a form with say, a checkbox, a selection, or some element to specify the ADFS route vs Cookie route, you collect your discriminating criteria, and on the Login post direct the action based on their choice.  You can decide if you like a client driven or server driven technique more.  Either way, the code can have that route or post data appendix to steer the route, and in `Startup`, you'd do something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory log, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Map(new PathString("oauth"), Action<IApplicationBuilder> x =>
        {  
            x.UseOAuthAuthentication(); ... 
        });

        app.Map(new PathString("cookie"), Action<IApplicationBuilder> x => {
 x.UseCookieAuthentication(); ....

    });
```

The general gist is that you establish a branch mapping if you need to support multiple Securities,
but if you are just engaging OAuth alone, just add the service in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service)`

and call the DI instance with your settings in

```
Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){

    app.USeCookieAuthentication();
```

}